# Change canvas region in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

By default, the top left corner of the canvas starts at (0,0). Is it possible to change this to a negative value? I want to move objects to the right/viewing window to the left.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw things at negative coordinates and then have them displayed at the upper-left corner by manipulating the `scrollregion` attribute.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

canvas.create_rectangle(-200, -200, -180, -180, fill="red")
canvas.create_rectangle(180, 180, 200, 200, fill="blue")

canvas.configure(scrollregion=(-200, -200, 200, 200))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If OP has a `scrollregion` larger than the canvas size originally, then this suggestion will deactivate the scrolling (if there are scrollbars originally).

Comment: @acw1668: yes, that is correct.